# When sending the result of this bash command to a file, I get an infinite loop

Tags: bash, unix, shell, scripting

I have a directory of file, and I want to print out their result and have it saved to a file. If I do the following, I can dump to STDOUT:

```
echo "[";
for i in ./*; do
    [[ -f $i ]] && cat $i; 
    echo ",";
done;
echo "]"
```

But if I do:

```
echo "[" < myfile.txt;
for i in ./*; do 
    [[ -f $i ]] && cat $i << myfile.txt;
    echo "," << myfile.txt;
 done;
 echo "]" << myfile.txt
```

I get stuck in an infinite loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean to use `>` and `>>` instead of `<` and `<<`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a file in `.`, then reading *and* writing to it simultaneously.  You need to store `myfile.txt` in a different directory than the one you're processing.

Also, I suggest this approach as a shorter form of what you're doing:

```
{ echo "[";
for i in ./*; do
    [[ -f $i ]] && cat $i;
    echo ",";
done;
echo "]"
} > ../myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `>>`, then at some point `$i` will equal `myfile.txt`, and you'll try and append it to itself...